# Howto import modules with dependencies in the same absolute/relative path with imp?

Tags: python, import

Is there a way to import modules with dependencies within the same directory using an absolute/relative path with "imp" ?

Here follows the directory structure:

```
.
├── importFrom
│   ├── dependant.py
│   └── dependence.py
└── test.py
```

file test.py imports dependant.py using:

```
modname=imp.load_source("testImp","importFrom/dependant.py")
```

which in turn imports dependence.py direcly with:

```
import dependence
```

Calling test.py gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    modname=imp.load_source("testImp","importFrom/dependant.py")
  File "importFrom/dependant.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dependence
ImportError: No module named dependence
```

It may be worthwhile to have load_source add the path to the loaded module to the loader so that it finds its relative dependencies automatically.
For now the only alternative I've found is adding to the system path, putting into test.py

Edit: I've found a better way to do the relative import with path, added **file** to get the absolute path of the caller (independence from current working directory)

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'importFrom'))
import dependant
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO this is not feasible with `load_source` which doesn't do necessary things so that import in your 'dependant.py' file consider its parent directory.

You should either do what have been suggested (`__init__.py` in the directory and absolute import in the module), or use lower-level find_module / load_module functions which allows this kind of things (see find_module 'path' argument)

Comment: Using 
    tup=imp.find_module("dependant",["/opt/importFrom/", "other"])
    imp.load_module("dependant",tup[0],tup[1],tup[2])

gives the same error "No module named dependence".

Comment: I also think it is not feasible with load_source as of python 2.7, hence correct answer is "not feasible", have to use workaround approach

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `__init__.py` in `importFrom` directory.

```
In [5]: ls importFrom/
dependance.py  dependant.pyc  dependence.pyc  __init__.pyc
dependant.py   dependence.py  __init__.py

In [6]: from importFrom import dependant

In [7]: dependant.dependence
Out[7]: <module 'importFrom.dependence' from    'importFrom/dependence.py'>
```

Instead of importing `dependant` in `test`, I have used Python interpreter to show the output. In `dependant.py`, `dependance` is imported.

Comment: This allows avoiding to add to the path for a standard import, it still does not work with imp.load_source, moreover I think it would also not work if the module to be imported is into a completely different directory

Comment: did to create a file __init__.py in the importFrom directory?

Comment: I created the __init__.py and placed an import importFrom.dependant in test.py which works. Still it works because the importFrom directory is direct child of the directory holding test.py an absolute path to it cannot be specified in a standard import.