# Using imp.load_source() throws "No module named .."

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I am using `imp` module to load a python file(exists at: `/parent_folder/path/to/my_module/my_module.py`) from source:

```
mod = imp.load_source("my_module", "/parent_folder/path/to/my_module/")
```

However, `my_module.py` file is also importing other modules written and saved in a same folder location:

```
    my_module.py
    ....
    ...
    from other_module import other_thing
    ...
```

The `load_source` fails complaining about `No module named other_module`. What would be the best way to load the file which handles all the imports? I would prefer achieving this by using python import library function rather than toying with the `sys.path`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto import modules with dependencies in the same absolute/relative path with imp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066777/howto-import-modules-with-dependencies-in-the-same-absolute-relative-path-with-i)

Answer (score 0):

Your path needs to include the full pathname to the file, including the '.py' at the end:

```
mod = imp.load_source("my_module", "/parent_folder/path/to/my_module/my_module.py")
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  Please provide a clear reason.  Otherwise, remove your downvote.  This is the correct answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

For me, explicitly importing the other dependency worked.

```
imp.load_source('path/to/other/module/other_module.py')
```

Try putting it before loading `my_module`.

Comment: `load_source` takes two arguments.