# Python - import a module directory given full path

Tags: python

I have a python module here `/root/python/foo.py`. I have a bunch of other modules here in the folder `/root/lib/` which looks like this

```
    lib/
    |
    ├─ module1/
    |  ├─ __init__.py
    |  └─ bar.py
    |
    └─ module2/
       ├─ __init__.py
       └─ bar.py
```

I would like to import `/root/lib/module1` and `/root/lib/module2` from `foo.py`. I would like to **not** have to add `/root/lib/` to the python system path. [This stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/1460845) tells you how to use either `imp.load_source`, `importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader`, or the `importlib.util` class to load a module from a file (depending on the python version). I think these only work if the module is a single file. If I try something like this in Python 3.4

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
problem_module = SourceFileLoader('test_mod', '/root/lib/module1').load_module()
```

I get an `IsADirectoryError`

My question is whether there is a similar way to load a module (given its full path) if it is a directory, without adding the whole `lib/` folder to the system path?

Comment: add `'` after module1

Comment: You need to use `sys.path` to reliably import modules.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066777/howto-import-modules-with-dependencies-in-the-same-absolute-relative-path-with-i).

Comment: "I would like to not have to add /root/lib/ to the python system path." - Why not?  It is *by far* the easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: I didn't want to add the directory to the system path because I thought I might have hundreds of modules in the library and I thought it would be nicer to target just the folder I wanted. Maybe adding the `lib` folder to the system path isn't as bad as I thought.

Answer (score 2):

**try:**

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
problem_module = SourceFileLoader('test_mod', '/root/lib/module1/__init__.py').load_module()
```

the `__init__.py` should take care about the modules in the same package:

add `from . import bar` to make `bar.py` part of the package.

Some corrections:

- `module1` is a package **not** a module.
- `bar.py` is a module part of the package `module1`

Comment: That sort of worked. I wanted to use module1 as a module name, e.g. I wanted to also import bar.py from module1 once it was loaded. Targeting the __init__.py alone didn't let me do that.

Comment: `from . import bar` in `__init__.py`

Comment: alternative solution: `from .bar import *`

Comment: I didn't want to have to import the over modules through the __init__.py file. I wanted to do something like `from problem_module import bar` but I guess if I had to do this it wouldn't be too bad, I would just have to change the way I work.

Comment: so you should replace `__init__.py` with `bar.py` (use formatting `%s.py`)

Comment: This was a huge help to me, thank you! I ran into an issue trying to import a file `foo.bar.py`, and `importlib` interpreted `foo`, `bar`, and `py` as modules.

Answer (score 2):

Python does not give us an easy way to load files that cannot be referenced by `sys.path`, most usual solution will do one of the following things:

1. Add desired paths to `sys.path` or
2. Restructure your modules so that the correct path is already on `sys.path`

**Nearly** all other solutions that does not do either will be work arounds (using non-intended methods to get the job done) and some can cause quite a headache.

However python does give us a mechanic that lets us simulate a package that is spread out across folders that are not held on `sys.path`, you can do this by [specifying a `__path__` special name](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories) in a module:

```
__path__ = ["/root/lib"]
```

Put this line in a file called `lib.py` and place it in the same folder as `foo.py` to be imported by it (so in `root/python/` in your case) then from `foo.py` you can do this as you would expect:

```
import lib.module1
#or
from lib import module1
```

This indicates to python that the `.module1` subpackage is located somewhere on the specified `__path__` and will be loaded from that directory (or multiple directories) using the intended import mechanisms and keeping your `sys.path` unaltered.

Comment: I think you're right and I might just have to end up adding the `lib` folder to the system.path. But if this is the right way to go then I'm wondering why python lets you import a module if it's just a file using `SourceFileLoader` (in python 3.4). If they had that functionality you'd think it wouldn't matter if it's a file or a directory.

Comment: Read the name... `Source` **`File`** `Loader`, you didn't specify a **file**, and loading a single module from source is not as simple as the whole import mechanism so I wouldn't count on it working 100% in any case.

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering why there wasn't a `SourceDirectoryLoader` method when there is a `SourceFileLoader`. But I guess you're right that it's not as simple as just using the import mechanism.

Comment: @pspencer I just found an actual solution using intended mechanisms, I think it is exactly what you need.

Comment: @Tadhq McDonald-Jensen Was the solution you were talking about the edit you made above about the `__path__` special name? That is an really interesting feature of python that I didn't know about but it was exactly what I was looking for. I was looking for a method like SourceFileLoader but for directories. I think what I've decided from this discussion is that there isn't a good pythonic way to do what I want except to just add the `lib` directory to the system path.